# PineScript - Stoploss Strategy / Average Price

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

Im using this script for "Stoploss" and "Take Profit":

```
// Stoploss

var stoploss = "StopLoss"

sl_inp = input(title="Stop Loss %", type=input.float, group=stoploss,defval=2.0)/100

tp_inp = input(title="Take Profit %", type=input.float, group=stoploss,defval=4.0)/100


// Stoploss calculation
 
stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)

take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)

// plot sl & tp

plot(sl_inp ? stop_level:an)

plot(tp_inp ? take_level:an)
```

I have 1 question and 1 issue:

Question:

I want to create a button to turn off/on the stoploss and profit-taking (separate one for each), I don't want it to show always. I know I have to make "input.bool" but when I insert "input.bool" in "sl_inp" or "tp_inp" it says the input should not be bool value.(I think its because of "/100"), so how can I create a turn off/on buttons for the mentioned plots when the inputs should be calculated as percentages?

Issue:

This script is using average price, and I think due to this, it is messing up the stoploss and profit take point when the market becomes more volatile. Is there a way to set it as the actual price of the bar and not the average price? (ex: 2% stoploss from the entry bar (Entry Bar: When Strategy detects an entry))

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see your question and problems, however I can only answer to what I see in your code (hopefully you've fixed it by now?)

A:
sl_inp = input.bool(true, "stop loss input?")

Do the same for the tp_inp.

B: stop_level and take_level are not needed in this way, You need strategy.entry and strategy.exit commands:

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}entry](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry)

C: gotta fix this:

plot(sl_inp ? stop_level:an)

plot(tp_inp ? take_level:an)

for maybe:

plot(sl_inp ? stop_level : na)

plot(tp_inp ? take_level : na)

as 'na' works however 'an' might be causing an error?
And again, once you've figured out the built-in strategy..... commands, You may not even want to use this type of plot and may end up potting something more fun like:

bg.color( in_trade ? color.new(color.green) : color.new(color.purple) : na)

Hope this helps!

Robin The PipSlayer
TekProtfitsTraders